# docker pull - stderr: layers from manifest don't match image configuration

Tags: docker

`stderr: layers from manifest don't match image configuration`

This is the error that I am receiving when I do a `docker pull` command. I have gone through and rebuilt every tag that my image relies upon, but I am still getting this.

Does anyone have some thoughts on where I should turn to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem when I upgrade docker from `1.6.2` to `18.06`.

Full discussion can be found in [github issue](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1439). From the tips of issue, I found  my solution:

- use docker 1.6.2 to pull the image, then `docker save -o /tmp/1.tar` export image to tar file
- upgrade docker to 18.06, then `docker load -i /tmp/1.tar` load image
- docker push this new image to registry, all work now

When I use docker 18.06 to execute `docker images`, the image pulled by `1.6.2` is show as follows:

```
REPOSITORY    TAG      IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>        <none>   c5c084240761        2 days ago          1.05GB
```

There must be some errors in metadata resulting in repository and tag are `<none>`. Therefore, I think reload the image may solve my problem.